# textDidChange method of UISearchBarDelegate has weird behavior with voice-to-text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, siri

I have a iPhone app that includes a `UITableView` with a `UISearchBar` at the top of it.  When a user types into the `UISearchBar` the `UITableView`'s contents are filtered appropriately.  When the user deletes all text in the `UISearchBar` the search bar ceases to be the first responder and the tableview becomes unfiltered once again.  Here is the relevant delegate code:

```
- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if(searchBar.text.length == 0)
    {
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        [self.myModel stopFiltering];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

The problem with this is, when a user speaks into their phone and attempts to do voice-to-text conversion (via Siri) in the search bar, the `textdidChange` method returns an empty string as search text.  Thus I have no way of knowing if the user is speaking into their phone or if they deleted all of the text in the field.  Is this behavior expected?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on the if statement? Can you step into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and check if you can step into the `IF statement` :

```
 - (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
    {
        if([searchText length]== 0)
        {
            [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
            [self.myModel stopFiltering];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([searchText length]> 0)
{
    [self searchTableView];
}
else
{
    [self btncloseClicked];
```

}

```
- (void)btncloseClicked
{
    [YourSearchBar performSelector: @selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject: nil afterDelay: 0.1];
    [table_View reloadData];
}
```